# Why local functions in PIC enabled binary don't use plt?

Tags: assembly, 64-bit

This is code lines i have used..

```
int global_func(int param)
{
    return param * 10;
}
int main()
{
    int a = global_func(10);
}
```

compile this code with -c -fPIC option to make object file and some results from the readelf.

```
readelf -d 

0000000000000015 <main>:
  15:   55                      push   %rbp
  16:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  19:   48 83 ec 20             sub    $0x20,%rsp
  1d:   89 7d ec                mov    %edi,-0x14(%rbp)
  20:   48 89 75 e0             mov    %rsi,-0x20(%rbp)
  24:   8b 45 ec                mov    -0x14(%rbp),%eax
  27:   89 c7                   mov    %eax,%edi
  29:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  2e <main+0x19>
```

---

```
readelf -r 

Relocation section '.rela.text' at offset 0x62438 contains 5 entries:
  Offset          Info           Type           Sym. Value    Sym. Name + Addend
00000000002a  000c00000004 R_X86_64_PLT32    0000000000000000 global_func - 4
```

It says 0x2a should be filled by the run-time loader and it is a R_X86_64_PLT32 type but, when i compile this object as a executable. I can find the executable doesn't call the plt before it calls global_func (e.g. global_func@plt)

why even ELF of the object file designate 0x2a should be a R_X86_64_PLT32 it doesn't call any PLT routine called in the shared library cases(e.g. printf@plt)?

Comment: Not sure why it needs to go through the PLT, but the call **is** to `global_func@plt` so I don't understand that part of your question.

Comment: I agree there is no need that global_func go through the PLT, but the dynamic sections says it needs to be located as a PLT32 type... and after it is compiled as an executable, call location just designate the some address that is not in the PLT area.. (if it is called by a plt it should be global_func@plt but just global_fun)

Comment: Indeed. Maybe the linker figured it out? See [binutils source](https://github.com/gittup/binutils/blob/gittup/bfd/elf64-x86-64.c#L1367): _"If this is a local symbol, we resolve it directly without creating a procedure linkage table entry."_